# Do Temporary Tables cause stored procedure Recompilations?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql

I have read certain articles online that creating temporary tables in stored procedures will cause stored procedure recompilations.

Could someone please explain what happens when a temporary table is created?

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please explain what happens when a temporary table is created

Temporary table is going to be created in TempDB

One thing for sure - creating temporary tables is NOT going to cause stored procedure recompilations.